# Login with Amazon - Button widget links to error page

Tags: javascript, button, amazon-web-services, login-with-amazon

I'm trying to integrate Amazon's "Login and Pay with Amazon" payment method into my webshop. I followed the steps from the developer docs: http://docs.developer.amazonservices.com/en_UK/apa_guide/APAGuide_GettingStarted.html

The problems starts at the very beginning. I inserted the code for the head part, and also the button widget (explained in Getting Started > Step 1). But when I click the button in my shop, the popup shows the following error:

[image]

It says there is a problem with the handling of my order (although I just expected a login screen). And Amazon is about to fix that problem. But I get this error since the very first time I clicked this button, and that's about a week ago. And I can't find any statements to this error.

Is there anything I could have done wrong? I think I setup everything right (client-id, seller-id, return-url, scope- and popup-parameters). Also the `onError` function isn't called, so I can't really do any debugging.

What causes the error?

Answer (score 1):

Have you setup the **Allowed JavaScript Origins** in application console? That might cause your problem.

Comment: I didn't set it because it says it's optional. And I don't use any own JavaScripts at the moment. Only this one from Amazon: 'https://static-eu.payments-amazon.com/OffAmazonPayments/uk/sandbox/lpa/js/Widgets.js' And I don't think I need to aloow Amazon-intern JSs... But also when I add its domain it doesn't change anything.

Comment: NO.. You have to enable SSL for your domain and need to fill the Allowed javascript origins.